# What .NET library can I use to solve optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, programming

I'm working with C# and I start being bored writing optimization algorithm.

Do you know any free library containing this sort of algorithms?

In particular I'm currently working with Semidefit program.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't had the time to try them personally, but if I were you I'd try [The Solver Foundation](http://www.solverfoundation.com/) or maybe you can find something useful within [these libraries](http://www.mathdotnet.com/About.aspx).

What I did was to compile a MATLAB algorithm and used the produced DLL.

**UPDATE:** I read yesterday in the Wilmott Magazine that the [NAG Library](http://www.nag.co.uk/netdevelopers.asp) is also available for .Net now. Again, I haven't used it and I don't know if you're looking for something open-source, but apparently this one is good.

Comment: NAG is not free. Very good and lots of value for the price, though.

Comment: @quant_dev: Do you know how much it costs for .Net? I couldn't find an answer on the site.

Comment: They don't have a fixed price. Call them. It depends on the number of cores it would be used on.

Answer (score 8):

You can use https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp

Other options:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/
and in R
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html

They all solve pure linear, integer and mixed problems

Comment: I heard Coin is very good.

Comment: Hmmm. the R libraries are not very easy to use from C#...

Answer (score 6):

You can also have a look at [**ALGLIB**](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/) or [**DotNumerics**](http://www.dotnumerics.com/NumericalLibraries/Optimization/Default.aspx).

It would help though if you clarified what kind of optimization problem you have or what kind of algorithm you look for. And if by **free** you mean ***GPL*** or something more like ***MIT***?

Comment: As said I'm currently working with semiefit program which can be solved by interior point methods. By free I mean free and usable on windows.

Comment: Then I assume you mean *free* as in *free beer*. ;-)

Comment: The OP probably doesn't want to pollute the code license with GPL.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid I don't know of any free, non-GPL, explicitly C# solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) or GSL contains a few different varieties of optimizer.  They work pretty well and have a relatively good interface.  Their derivative-aware routines are a bit lacking in bounded optimization features compared to NAG, though.

Comment: GSL has *no* constrained nonlinear optimizers which use derivatives.